# How to use Pydantic2 and Sqlalchemy to serialize nested data in FastAPI

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I have a following problem. I have a relationship One to One between User model and Profile model (one user can only have one profile). I use postgres, sqlalchemy, pydantic and fastAPI. Code looks likes this:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        nullable=False,
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
    )
    ...<some other fields>
    profile = relationship("Profile", back_populates="user")
```

and

```
class Profile(Base):
    __tablename__ = "profiles"

    id = Column(
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        nullable=False,
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
    )
    user_id = Column(
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        ForeignKey("users.id"),
        nullable=False,
        unique=True,
    )
    user = relationship(
        "User",
        foreign_keys="Profile.user_id",
        back_populates="profile"
    )
    ...<some other fields>
```

Now, when I get Profile in the following router:

```
@router.get(
    "{user_id}",
    status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
    response_model=ReadProfile,
)
async def get_profile_read(
    profile_id: str,
    profile_service: ProfilesService = Depends(get_profiles_service),
    current_user: str = Depends(get_auth),
):
    profile = await profile_service.get(profile_id)
    return ReadProfile(**profile.__dict__)
```

I'd like to have definition of fields that will be returned defined by pydantic model which looks as follows:

```
class ReadProfile(BaseModel):
    id: UUID
    ...<some other data>
    user: ReadUser
```

ReadUser looks like this

```
class ReadUser(BaseModel):
    id: UUID
    ...some other data
```

and the method that reads Profile from db looks like this:

```
async def get(self, profile_id: str) -> ReadProfile:
    q = await self.db_session.execute(
        select(Profile)
        .where(Profile.id == profile_id)
        .options(
            selectinload(Profile.user)
        )
    )
    result = q.scalars().first()
    if not result:
        raise ValueError("Profile not found!")
    return result
```

When I print result._ *dict* _ I can see that there is a User model under the attribute "user". Proof:

```
{'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7faf6cccb820>, 'user_id': UUID('619949c3-a17c-4d59-90fa-b332307a4597'), 'display_name': 'mfoxen0', 'gender': <GenderEnum.female: 'female'>, 'date_modified': datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 23, 19, 12, 2, 98185, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'id': UUID('51cdf177-d12d-40e9-8cb3-028f76a762f3'), 'bio': 'venenatis turpis enim blandit mi in porttitor pede justo eu massa donec dapibus', 'date_created': datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 23, 19, 12, 2, 98185, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'user': <app.models.user.User object at 0x7faf6f89d420>}
```

But for some reason pydantic crashes with an error:

```
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for ReadProfile
web_1      | user
web_1      |   Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of ReadUser [type=model_type, input_value=<app.models.user.User object at 0x7f8b7c3cca30>, input_type=User]
```

What am I doing wrong and how to sort it out? Thanks to everyone who read this :)

Comment: If you want to allow reading SQLAlchemy objects - don't use the `__dict__` creation method - that won't work with linked objects, as they won't get "exploded" as in that case. Instead, define the pydantic models to allow loading from regular class properties: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#arbitrary-class-instances (previously known as `orm_mode` in Pydantic v1) - `model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)` is the syntax for v2 (as a property on the model class).

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks, It worked! I don't know how to mark your post as a solution to the problem.